# React18 Micro Task Batch Processing Problem

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("render");
});

const handleClick = () => {
  setC1((c) => c + 1);

  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    setC1((c) => c + 1);
  });
};

const handleClick2 = () => {
  Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    setC1((c) => c + 1);
  });

  setC1((c) => c + 1);
};
```

In the React18 version, why does clicking on the `handleClick` method result in two renderings, while clicking on the `handleClick2` method only results in one rendering?

I expect the output of both methods to be the same. Can someone tell me why they are different?

Comment: Maybe it's a bug, see https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24365

Comment: @LinDu Thank you very much for your answer. It should be this question

Answer (score 1):

I will explain how these call orders are different, and how the observed behavior is possible.

I can not tell you exactly how React internally batches the state updates,
I just assume that React does sophisticated optimizations, which are not supposed to be relevant to developers who are using React, and require an in-depth understanding of the React-internals, and might even change from one release to another. *(Feel free to correct me.)*

#### The difference

`Promise.resolve()` schedules a new microtask, and is effectively equivalent to [`window.queueMicrotask()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/queueMicrotask).

The `setState` functions *(might)* also schedule a new microtask,
so their callbacks are both (the `Promise` and the `setState`) invoked in the same execution phase.

The difference between the two variants is that

- in `handleClickA` a `setState2` hook is called between the two `updater` functions, while
- in `handleClickB` both `updater` functions are called directly one after the other.

#### Example code

I rewrite your code a bit, to illustrate the call order a bit better:

```
const setState1 = setState;     
const setState2 = setState;
const update1 = updaterFunction; // c => c + 1
const update2 = updaterFunction; // c => c + 1

const handleClickA = () => {          
                                  // Scheduled functions:
    setState1( update1 );         // 1. --> [ update1 ]
    
    queueMicrotask(() => {        // 2. --> [ update1, setState2 ]
        setState2( update2 );     // 4. --> [ update2 ]
    });

    // update1();                 // 3. --> [ setState2 ]
    // setState2( update2 );      // 4. --> [ update2 ]
    // update2();                 // 5. --> []
};

const handleClickB = () => {
                                  // Scheduled functions:    
    queueMicrotask(() => {        // 1. --> [ setState2 ]
        setState2( update2 );     // 3. --> [ update2 ]
    });

    setState1( update1 );         // 2. --> [ setState2, update1 ]
    
    // setState2( update2 );      // 3. --> [ update1, update2 ]
    // update1();                 // 4. --> [ update2 ]
    // update2();                 // 5. --> []
};
```

#### Call order illustration

Here I illustrate the call order.

On the right side is which functions are currently queued to be called ([FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics))):

`handleClickA`:

```
                                  // 0. --> []
- schedule update1 (setState1())  // 1. --> [ update1 ]
- schedule setState2              // 2. --> [ update1, setState2 ]
- invoke update1()                // 3. --> [ setState2 ]
- schedule update2 (setState2())  // 4. --> [ update2 ]
- invoke update2()                // 5. --> []
```

`handleClickB`:

```
                                // 0. --> []
schedule setState2              // 1. --> [ setState2 ]
schedule update1 (setState1())  // 2. --> [ setState2, update1 ]
schedule update2 (setState2())  // 3. --> [ update1, update2 ]
invoke update1()                // 4. --> [ update2 ]
invoke update2()                // 5. --> []
```

#### Personal interpretation

I assume that React tries to batch all the `updater` functions which are currently queued.

I.e. as long as only updater functions are called, try to **batch them together** and update the final state **only once**.

But if there is a new `setState` function invoked, React probably **finishes the current updating loop** and starts a new render cycle before invoking the next `updater` function.

I could only guess why this is done, maybe

- because the new `setState` might break the batching somehow, or
- the next render would be delayed too much if new `setState` calls were invoked recursively, or
- the React people are just still working on the best optimization strategies and their tradeoffs.
- (... or it's a bug.)